# Laravel Return Siblings Results in Non-Object situation

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a table of users that are imported to the DB. I keep their original id as reference_id:

```
id    |  reference_id   |   parent_id
1           35                null
2           36                 35
3           37                 35
4           38                null
5           37                 38
```

I am trying to get back the entire family. In laravel I am using this in the model:

```
public function getFamily(){
    $parent = User::where('user_id', auth()->id())
    ->where('parent_id', $this->parent_id)->get();

    $children = User::where('user_id', auth()->id())
    ->where('reference_id', $this->parent_id)->get();

    return $parent->merge($children);
}
```

and then in the blade template calling it like this:

```
$family= $tasks->user->getFamily();

foreach($family as $member){
    print_r($member->appointments->some_field);
}
```

I am getting an error when I do the `print_r` that I am trying to call on a non-object and I am not sure what to do about it. Appointments refers to another model / table.

In the rest of the User model I was able to do it more simply with something like this:

```
public function getFamily(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\User', 'reference_id', 'parent_id');
        ->where('user_id', auth()->id())
        ->where('parent_id', $this->parent_id);
}
```

This particular one "should" have returned all the siblings when called like this: `$family= $tasks->user->getFamily` and then I could have accessed the Appointments Model, but I was getting an error that I was running out of memory trying to use about 1.6Gb:

```
[2018-02-14 00:25:15] local.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException: Allowed memory size of 2634022912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1608531968 bytes) in /var/www/html/laravel/storage/framework/views/bcfe7a474602582174256aacc1597a287fcb4e5e.php:213
```

Is there any way to adapt my first and working function to also allow me to join on associated tables? Barring that, is there something obvious I am missing in the second query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by changing the `getFamily` function to a [local scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#local-scopes).

```
public function scopeFamily ($query) {
    return $query->where('id', auth()->id())->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('parent_id', $this->parent_id)
              ->orWhere('reference_id', $this->parent_id);
    });
}
```

You  should then have access to all `Appointment` models via:

```
$appointments = User::family()->each->appointments;
```

**edit**

```
public function scopeFamily($query, $parentId) {
    if(isset($parentId)){
        return $query->where('user_id', auth()->id())->where(function ($query) use ($parentId) {
            $query->where('parent_id', $parentId)
                  ->orWhere('reference_id', $parentId);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested and don't get anything returned at all. I am trying to return to a variable that can then be looped over again to find all appointments for each family member. I used the following:   `$family  = App\Models\User::family()->get();

if($family){
    foreach($family as $member){
        print_r($member);
    }
}`

Comment: Within the scopeFamily I am trying to `print_r` the value of `$this` and it is null which is probably why I am not getting any results. How can I pass more info to the function?

Comment: You can add more arguments to the function: `public function scopeFamily ($query, $arg1, $arg2, ...$args) {`. That makes it a [dynamic scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#local-scopes).

Comment: Thanks, for some reason there is still an issue with undefined variables... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48779639/laravel-undefined-variable-using-isset

Comment: Oh you need to be using a `use` statement here: `return $query->where('id', auth()->id())->where(function ($query) use ($parentId) {`

Comment: When passing closures as method parameters, you're effectively changing the context in which the code is executing. Within `where(function ($query) { ... })`, the script doesn't have any reference to $parentId, so `use` allows you to pass variables in.