# Laravel Undefined Variable - Using isset()

Tags: php, laravel-5

I was working with someone on this other question: [Laravel Return Siblings Results in Non-Object situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48778405/laravel-return-siblings-results-in-non-object-situation) and in implementing their solution it fails regardless of how many times I try error handling.

In my model I have this:

```
public function scopeFamily($query, $parentId) {
    if(isset($parentId)){
        return $query->where('user_id', auth()->id())->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('parent_id', $parentId)
                  ->orWhere('reference_id', $parentId);
        });
    }
}
```

Then in the blade template I am calling it using this:

```
if(isset($tasks->user->parent_id)){
    $parentId = $tasks->user->parent_id;
    if(isset($parentId)){
      $family =  App\Models\User::family($parentId)->get();
    }
}
```

I get the error `Undefined variable: parentId`. That shouldn't be possible should it? I know not all records in the DB have a parent_id, but the first `isset()` should have eliminated those.

Comment: Did you used `use` keyword to use `parentId`

Comment: I don't understand how or why I would use the `use` keyword. The error seems to be thrown within the model, even though it comes through as an argument and so is set at execution time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In model use `use` keyword. When we have to access the variable which is outside of the closure, need to use `use`  keyword to access those.

```
public function scopeFamily($query, $parentId) {
  if(isset($parentId)){
    return $query->where('user_id', auth()->id())->where(function ($query) use ($parentId){
        $query->where('parent_id', $parentId)
              ->orWhere('reference_id', $parentId);
    });
  }
}
```